# Qtip2 tooltip integration with FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, tooltip, qtip2

I am trying to implement Qtip2 tooltip in the FullCalendar jquery plugin. The Qtip2 and FullCalendar both are really nice jQuery plugin and easy implement.

I have done Qtip2 integration in my FullCalendar plugin as suggested in their `http://qtip2.com/demos` page.

But even in the demo i have found error like, The tooltip is just moving away from the events (Particularly when i click & close on one event and move to another event, you can see that it will move away from the Grid)

Their view source page: `http://jsfiddle.net/qTip2/T9GHJ/`

Steps to find issue:

1. Click on any event and Close the tooltip
2. And Click on another event and Close the tooltip and Continue the same.

I am just stuck on this for long time. I couldn't able to find solution for that. Any help on this would be appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with qtips for some time too, but here is the code that finally worked for me. It prevents buggy and seemingly random behaviour, especially when moving your mouse around or dragging the events.

Call this function from fullCalendar's eventRender. `element` is the second parameters passed in eventRender function, and the rest are optional (options object containing tooltip's `title` and `text`, `target` as defined in qTip2 docs, and `hideEvents` which is a space-separated list of JS events that will hide the tooltip when they are fired, such as `"mousedown mouseup mouseleave"`).

```
/** adds a tooltip to a specified element, like an event or resource */
function addToolTip(element, o, target, hideEvents) {
    if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        target = false;
    }
    if (hideEvents === undefined) {
        hideEvents = "mousedown mouseup mouseleave";
    }
    element.qtip({
        content: {
            title: o.title,
            text: o.text
        }
        , position: {
            my: "bottom center",
            at: "top center",
            target: target // "mouse" is buggy when dragging and interferes with clicking
            //adjust: { y: -9}
        }
        , style: {
            tip: { corner: 'bottom center' },
            classes: 'qtip-light qtip-shadow'
        },
        show: {
            effect: function () {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 1);
            },
            solo: true,
            delay: 200
        },
        hide: {
            effect: true,
            event: hideEvents // otherwise stays while dragging
        }
    });
}
```